# User-Agent information does not helps to identify if request comes from iPAD or MAC OS in Safari Browser

Tags: user-agent

I am trying to know if the rest API request is coming from the iPad / mac OS of the safari browser. But, USER-AGENT header information remains the same for iPad & mac from safari browser.

Looking forward to knowing the answer if anyone found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you query - "navigator.appVersion" it gives the same value for Mac and IPAD for Safari browser. But you can use an alternate property like - "navigator.maxTouchPoints" which gives a value of 5 on IPAD and 0 on mac. This can be used to differentiate the user agent rather than picking it up from the request header.